# Help with 2D sprite instancing

Tags: opengl, c++, 2d, glsl

Alright, so I'm pretty new to OpenGL programming. I've been writing my own engine, initially using the fixed function pipeline. I then did a 1:1 replacement of the fixed-function methods with shaders and it all worked perfectly (but slow, I wasn't instancing things then).

My game is only 2D but I need my engine be as efficient as possible because I'm planning on doing all sorts of intense effects like particles and real-time per-pixel lighting.

## The Plan:

My game's sprites are all contained in one giant texture atlas and the dimensions of their cells are never going to change. I decided that I'll store all the cell data in a `Uniform Buffer Object` as a `GL_STATIC_DRAW` so I don't waste time resending data that never changes.

In my render loop my engine buffers sprite positions and cellIDs as `Instance` objects in a `std::vector`. At the end of the render loop I send the contents of the `std::vector` to the GPU and tell it to render them as instances using the data in the `UBO`.

I've attempted an implementation of this idea but now it doesn't *appear* to render anything (I'm left with a black screen) while spitting out no errors. I know I haven't broken OpenGL (too badly) because my fixed-function replacement code for rendering primitive solids still works alongside it.

## The Broken Implementation:

Note I'm using:

- C++
- OpenGL 3.3
- GLFW
- GLEW
- OpenGL Mathematics (GLM)

Here's the code for the cells contained within the UBO:

```
struct UBO_Cell {  
    glm::vec2 vert[4]; // Simple XY corners (could just make it W/H and save 2 vec2s)
    glm::vec2 tex[4]; // [0..1] texel coordinates.
};
```

Here's the code that creates the UBO:

```
void Texture::CreateUniformBufferObject() {
    uboReady = true;
    for( int i = 0; i < numberOfCells; ++i ) {
        ubo[i].vert[0].x = cells[i].clip.x;
        ubo[i].vert[0].y = cells[i].clip.y;
        ubo[i].vert[1].x = cells[i].clip.x + cells[i].clip.w;
        ubo[i].vert[1].y = cells[i].clip.y;
        ubo[i].vert[2].x = cells[i].clip.x + cells[i].clip.w;
        ubo[i].vert[2].y = cells[i].clip.y + cells[i].clip.h;
        ubo[i].vert[3].x = cells[i].clip.x;
        ubo[i].vert[3].y = cells[i].clip.y + cells[i].clip.h;

        ubo[i].tex[0].x = ( cells[i].clip.x + TEXEL_SHRINK ) / texW;
        ubo[i].tex[0].y = ( cells[i].clip.y + TEXEL_SHRINK ) / texH;
        ubo[i].tex[1].x = ( cells[i].clip.x + cells[i].clip.w - TEXEL_SHRINK ) / texW;
        ubo[i].tex[1].y = ( cells[i].clip.y + TEXEL_SHRINK ) / texH;
        ubo[i].tex[2].x = ( cells[i].clip.x + cells[i].clip.w - TEXEL_SHRINK ) / texW;
        ubo[i].tex[2].y = ( cells[i].clip.y + cells[i].clip.h - TEXEL_SHRINK ) / texH;
        ubo[i].tex[3].x = ( cells[i].clip.x + TEXEL_SHRINK ) / texW;
        ubo[i].tex[3].y = ( cells[i].clip.y + cells[i].clip.h - TEXEL_SHRINK ) / texH;
    }
}
```

Here's the code for each `Instance` object:

```
struct Instance {
    glm::mat4 transform; // transform/scale/rotation matrix to put the instance where it needs to be (calculated CPU side for the moment).
    glm::uint cellID; // Index of this sprite's cell in the cell array
};
```

Here's my vertex shader:

```
#version 330

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

#define MAX_NUM_OF_CELLS 512 // Arbitrary maximum

struct Cell { // Mirror of the C++ struct.
    vec2 vert[4];
    vec2 tex[4];
};

layout(std140) uniform Cells { // The UBO with the cells.
    Cell cells[MAX_NUM_OF_CELLS];
}; // Perhaps I should use instance_name[MAX_NUM_OF_CELLS] instead?

// The transform and cellID are sent as VBOs.
in mat4 in_transformMatrix;
flat in uint in_cellID;

flat out int vertID; // So I can pass the vertex ID to the fragment shader.

void main() {
    vertID = gl_VertexID; // I'm assuming this goes from 0..3 when rendering a quad?
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * in_transformMatrix * vec4( cells[cellID].vert[vertID].x, cells[cellID].vert[vertID].y, 0.0, 1.0 );
};
```

Here's the fragment shader:

```
#version 330

uniform sampler2D textureUnit;

const vec4 texColour = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

#define MAX_NUM_OF_CELLS 512

struct Cell{
    vec2 vert[4];
    vec2 tex[4];
};

layout(std140) uniform Cells {
    Cell cells[MAX_NUM_OF_CELLS];
};

flat in uint in_cellID;
flat in int vertID;

out vec4 out_fragColour;

void main() {
    out_fragColour = texture2D( textureUnit, cells[in_cellID].tex[vertID] ) * texColour;
};
```

If it helps, here's how I set up my shader buffers:

```
void TextureShader::GenerateBuffers() {
    glGenBuffers( 1, &cellBufferID );
    glBindBuffer( GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, cellBlockID );
    glBufferData( GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof( UBO_Cell ) * MAX_NUM_OF_UBO_CELLS, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    glBindBuffer( GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0 );

    glGenBuffers( 1, &instanceBufferID );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceBufferID );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( Texture::Instance ) * 1024, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );

    glGenBuffers( 1, &ibo );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo );
    glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(GLuint), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
}
```

And here's my drawing function:

```
// Switch Program
glUseProgram( id ); // Because I switch between this and the shader I use to render primitives.

// Setting Projection Matrix
glm::mat4 projectionMatrix = NuWindow::GetProjectionMatrix(); // This will get factored out eventually.
glUniformMatrix4fv( projectionMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&projectionMatrix );

// Binding Texture
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID );

// Binding Buffers
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceBufferID );
glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo );
glUniformBlockBinding( id, cellLocation, 1 );
glBindBufferBase( GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 1, cellBufferID ); // As far as I know this binds the buffer like glBindBuffer() as well.

// Enabling Vertex Array Attributes
glEnableVertexAttribArray( transformMatrixLocation ); // A mat4 in GLSL takes up 4 locations.
glEnableVertexAttribArray( transformMatrixLocation + 1 );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( transformMatrixLocation + 2 );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( transformMatrixLocation + 3 );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( cellIdLocation );

// Buffering Instances as a VBO
glVertexAttribPointer( transformMatrixLocation, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof( Texture::Instance ), (GLvoid*)offsetof( Texture::Instance, transform ) );
glVertexAttribPointer( transformMatrixLocation + 1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof( Texture::Instance ), (GLvoid*)( offsetof( Texture::Instance, transform ) + sizeof( GLfloat ) * 4) );
glVertexAttribPointer( transformMatrixLocation + 2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof( Texture::Instance ), (GLvoid*)( offsetof( Texture::Instance, transform ) + sizeof( GLfloat ) * 8) );
glVertexAttribPointer( transformMatrixLocation + 3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof( Texture::Instance ), (GLvoid*)( offsetof( Texture::Instance, transform ) + sizeof( GLfloat ) * 12) );
glVertexAttribPointer( cellIdLocation, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, GL_FALSE, sizeof( Texture::Instance ), (GLvoid*)offsetof( Texture::Instance, cellID ) );
glVertexAttribDivisor( transformMatrixLocation, 1); // Each one of these is only a per-instance thing.
glVertexAttribDivisor( transformMatrixLocation + 1, 1);
glVertexAttribDivisor( transformMatrixLocation + 2, 1);
glVertexAttribDivisor( transformMatrixLocation + 3, 1);
glVertexAttribDivisor( cellIdLocation, 1);
//glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( Texture::Instance ) * instances.size(), instances.data(), GL_STREAM_DRAW );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( Texture::Instance ), (GLvoid*)&dummy_instance, GL_STREAM_DRAW );

// Setting the IBO
GLuint indicies[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 }; // This is where I think I'm going wrong, I'm not 100% where the IBO comes into this process.
                                    // Does this feed into GLSL's gl_VertexID? If it does it works as I expect a tiny bit.
glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(GLuint), (GLvoid*)&indicies, GL_STREAM_DRAW );

// Setting the UBO
if( !texture->uboReady ) texture->CreateUniformBufferObject(); // Creates the std::vector of UBO_Cells if I doesn't exist already.
glBufferData( GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof( UBO_Cell ) * MAX_NUM_OF_UBO_CELLS, &(texture->ubo), GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    // Yes I know I said this was supposed to be fire and forget but I wanted all this code in the one place for debugging.

// Drawing
glDrawElementsInstanced( GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, instances.size() );

// Disabling Vertex Attributes
glDisableVertexAttribArray( transformMatrixLocation );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( transformMatrixLocation + 1 );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( transformMatrixLocation + 2 );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( transformMatrixLocation + 3 );
glDisableVertexAttribArray( cellIdLocation );

// Unbinding Buffers
glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
glBindBuffer( GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0 );
```

---

I've been staring at this code for weeks and I can't find out what's wrong. I guess its either something really small or maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree.

---

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can give me, I'd put a bounty on this thing but don't have enough rep!

Comment: I'd take a closer look if I had the time, but it seems over-complicated for 2D drawing, especially your drawing function. Take a step back, and get a triangle/quad displaying on screen without any of the extras? And I recommend looking into vertex array objects, so that you don't need to do quite so many binds/unbinds and state changes during your drawing function.

Comment: Well I'd like to help, but only have the time to link you to my implementation. I finished 2D instancing myself (first time, not familiar with OpenGL either), so you can take a look at the source. I used a texture buffer object, which is more efficient than a uniform array (and has less strict memory requirements). Note that I build the transforms of each sprite on the GPU: https://bitbucket.org/rgaul/sel/src. If you have questions you can contact me.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? You should post an answer if you were.

Comment: Alas, no. Instead of hoping the internet would solve my problems for me I bought a few books on the topic (OpenGL SuperBible most notably) and realised that my implementation was so bad I decided to start all over.

Now if this question could somehow be closed, that would be nice.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging your code for you.